# Tomcat Management using Ansible

Tags: java, tomcat, ansible, conditional-statements

I am writing a playbook where i need to stop/start tomcat using ansible. In a normal scenario we execute this command on the server to start/stop tomcat - `svcadm disable/enable tomcat` and to check the status we do `svcs tomcat`.

I need to do the same thing from Ansible but need to put some conditions to make sure it is executed fine because only after tomcat has shutdown properly, my main playbook will execute further to deploy the code

Below is my simple playbook for tomcat role -

```
---
- name: Stop tomcat service
  shell: "svcadm disable tomcat"
```

The Problem here is sometimes after executing this command it goes into MAINTENANCE mode. We check the status by using `svcs tomcat` and if it's in MAINTENANCE mode then we need to execute the command again to make sure it goes to DISABLED state. Also we double verify it by executing `ps -ef | grep java` command to make sure no tomcat running.

Is it possible to achieve this from Ansible by putting some conditions. Let me know if someone can help.

Comment: Do you have a service to manage your tomcat? What happen if you run twice the stop? What is the output of the svcs command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`service` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html) supports solaris SMF. This should be as easy as the following task and will respect idempotency:

```yaml
- name: Stop tomcat
  service:
    name: tomcat
    state: stopped
    enabled: no
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try that. But I was thinking of using the same steps as we currently execute manually and svcadm rnable/disable command we use atm for tomcat services.

Comment: It is actually not a good idea to fire shell commands when you have a module doing the job and managing idempotency for you. You can run the above as many times as you like. It will report "changed" if it had to stop and/or disable tomcat, "ok" if it was already in that state.

Comment: I agree. Let me try that and see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: I tried using the service module but again the same problem. It went to maintenence mode rather than disabled. When i again tried to run the module nothing happened. That's why I was trying to fire the shell commands and may be looking for a condition to check if it's in "maintenance" mode run it again.

Comment: This seems to be rather specific to Solaris and I don't have a clue of why it behaves like this.